# Extracting csrf-token attribute using Ext.core

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

Given this HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sencha on Rails</title>
  <!-- styles, scripts etc. -->
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="JzrbB8G0gpcKoWcnL8+AllPSXzUVwqDSp5yjgEGqYwk=" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

How would I use [Ext.core](http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/) to extract the csrf-token?

In jQuery, I could do this:

```
var csrfToken = jQuery("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content");
> "JzrbB8G0gpcKoWcnL8+AllPSXzUVwqDSp5yjgEGqYwk="
```

I'm building a Sencha Touch application backed by rails, so I can't use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ext.query(selector,root);` to get the token.

For example:

```
var csrfToken = Ext.query('meta[name=csrf-token]')[0].getAttribute('content');
```

Note that `Ext.query` returns an *array* of components that matched the query. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery.Query-method-query

Or you can use `Ext.select`

```
var csrfToken = Ext.select('meta[name=csrf-token]').elements[0].getAttribute('content');
```